# Why .ToPagedList works so slowly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering how exactly paging works on a dataset drawn from the database. In my example I do some searching and filtering on a table and pass those values to controller. I also pass `page` to `.ToPagedList`.

I noticed that paging works slow (when I change page to next one it takes time). That's why I'm asking how `.ToPagedList` really works and what's the benefit from using it.

In my example - every time I change page number `Index` action is invoked and connection to the database is established. The whole dataset is filtered, then the outcome turns into a `PagedList`. Then I can see that I'm on the given page but it really takes time.

When I change page then again - Index Action is invoked, it connects to the database and draw dataset, filters and return outcome to given page. Maybe I'm wrong but it in terms of performance it's really slow method and consumes lots of memory.

View:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<XYZ.Models.DocumentsModel>

// some code here

<tr>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
<th>               
    @Html.TextBox("Account")
</th>   

<th>
    @Html.TextBox("Inv")
</th>

<th>
     @Html.DropDownList("filterList", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
            new SelectListItem { Text="", Value= "", Selected=true},
            new SelectListItem { Text="None", Value="None"},
           })
     
     <input type="button" class="search" value="filter" />

</th>
}
</tr>


@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
    page,
    Account = Request.QueryString["Account"],
    Invoice = Request.QueryString["Inv"],
    filterList = Request.QueryString["filterList"]

})
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IDocuments _docs;

    public HomeController(IDocuments docs)
    {
        _docs = docs;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int? page, string filterList, string Account, string Invoice)
    {
        var docsModel = _docs.GetAll();

        var model = docsModel.Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Account) || w.docsModel.FOPKTO.Contains(Account))
                             .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Invoice) || w.docsModel.FOPLBN.Contains(Invoice))
                             .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterList) || w.docsModel.DECISION == filterList)
                             .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                               {
                                   Account = s.docsModel.FOPKTO.Trim(),
                                   Date = s.docsModel.FOPBDA
                               })
                             .OrderBy(o => o.Date)
                             .ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 15); 

    return View(model);
}
```

Interface:

```
public class DocumentsService : IDocuments
{
    private MYdb _context;

    public DocumentsService(MYdb context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DocumentsTableSQL> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.DocumentsTableSQL.AsNoTracking();
    }
}
```

As you can see every time when page is changed, then the `Index` action is invoked and database is being queried, it costs time and memory. I thought that `PagedList` in some way keeps outcome and does not let database be queried all the time when page is changed.

**EDIT:**

I added ```_docs`` to Controller code and Interface as to show how data is extracted from db. I inject dependency into controller.

Comment: You're doing a GetAll() first and then filter the result. Is _docs coming from a DB? Second is there any heavy code in de constructor of the DocumentsModel?

Comment: My best bet would be to exchange the docsModel in your query with _docs. If _docs comes from the DB with GetAll() it will first get all rows into memory and then filtter them. With _docs as the source the query to the DB will contain the filter and should be much faster.

Comment: @PaulSinnema please take a look now. I added some code to Controller from my project as well as Interface. I also showe GetAll() method. I inject dependency. Based on this could you say what is wrong with it? GetAll() is just a simple method retrieving data from DB. And I use this data in controller. Don't know why it would slow down the code?

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: many, around 100 I guess.

Comment: 100 is not many

Comment: ok, but it still work slowly. I'll talk to my colleagues, maybe it's sth from the server side

Comment: please answer my questions

Comment: Ok, so I used dependency injection here. By using _docs I can refer to methods of DocumentsSrrvice class (this class implements my interface). So, _docs is not coming from DB. I can get extract data from DB using ```var docsModel = _docs.GetAll();``` where GetAll() method returns data from DB table. As for constructor - there's no heavy code one, just default.

Comment: I also changed my code and insetad of using ```var docsModel = _docs.GetAll();``` I used directly DB table in model, I mean: ```var model=DocumentsTableSQL.AsNoTracking().Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Account).....``` but it also doesn not solve my problem, it works as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in how to compose your select. At the moment you do your .Select(s => new DocumentsModel ...) the list is resolved into memory taking all rows from the DB. The OrderBy() and ToPagedList() are all executed on all the rows in memory. Below I have sort of your application using a local DB on my system. The table read is Courses which contains a lot of rows.

Executing the code below gives this result:

---

```
Getting list 1 took 2289 milliseconds
Getting list 2 took 46 milliseconds
```

---

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ToPagedList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            var list1 = Repository.GetCourses1();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Getting list 1 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");


            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            var list2 = Repository.GetCourses2();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Getting list 2 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The difference in the code below is where you put the .Select() statement.

- In the first list the whole table is read into the Select() before you do the sort.
- In the second list only 15 rows of the table are read. The OrderBy() is done in the database and not in memory.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ToPagedList
{
    public class Repository
    {
        public static List<DocumentsModel> GetCourses1(string school = null, string code = null, string title = null, int page = 0, int count = 15)
        {
            var courses = new DocumentModelEntities().Course;

            return courses.Where(course => string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || course.CourseCode.Contains(code))
                                 .Where(course => String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || course.Title.Contains(title))
                                 .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(school) || w.School == school)
                                 // From here your table is read from the DB using the where clauses
                                 .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                                 {
                                     Code = code.Trim(),
                                     Title = s.Title
                                 })
                                 .OrderBy(o => o.Code)
                                 .Skip(page * count)
                                 .Take(count)
                                 .ToList();
        }

        public static List<DocumentsModel> GetCourses2(string school = null, string code = null, string title = null, int page = 0, int count = 15)
        {
            var courses = new DocumentModelEntities().Course;

            return courses.Where(course => string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || course.CourseCode.Contains(code))
                             .Where(course => String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || course.Title.Contains(title))
                             .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(school) || w.School == school)
                             .OrderBy(course => course.CourseCode)
                             .Skip(page * count)
                             .Take(count)
                             // From here your table is read from the DB using the where clauses, order by, skip and take
                             .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                             {
                                 Code = code.Trim(),
                                 Title = s.Title
                             })
                             .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the effort you put into the answer, I really appreciate it:) I followed your code and noticed that app works a little bit faster. The issue is that changing page is as slow as before, it doesn't work instantly

Comment: Put some logging in your code and try to determine where the most processing time is lost. You can use the Stopwacht() construct I use in my code.

Comment: And also take a look in the browser with F12 key (Debugging). You can see execution times there too (look on the 'Network' tab. Maybe it's not the controller that causing a problem. Maybe it's something else in your page. Does it cause a full roundtrip or are you using partial rendering of the page?

Comment: Today I talked to my colleague programmer, he was also curious about it, couldn't find an answer right away. He will delve into my code and let me know